# Use "pairwise.complete.obs" in correlation() function

Tags: r, correlation

I am making a correlation matrix and I need to have, in addition to the correlation coefficient, the p-value. One of the tools that allows me to do that is the `correlation()` package, however, I can't find the methods to deal with missing values, as with the `cor()` package.

By default `cor()` uses the "everything" method, however that eliminates my columns with missing data; the "pairwise.complete.obs" method, in `cor()`, allows me to use the complete data pairs of the variables to correlate, without losing the variable with missing data and is the same method that `correlation()` uses by default. However I would like to be able to choose other methods in `correlation()` to deal with missing data and I can't find a way to do it.

```
a <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  check.names = FALSE,
  `A` = c(2.8,3.4,11.81,2.98,4.09,
              4.68,4.8,2.89,1.47,2.42,1.71,4.61,5.57,1.43),
  `B` = c(2.54,2.75,2.01,2.14,2.34,
              1.82,6.9,1.91,1.12,1.4,1.21,0.9,1.63,0.95),
  `C` = c(2.88,2.83,2.75,2.94,2.93,
              1.98,7.58,2.1,1.1,1.59,1.23,1.68,4.11,1.14),
  `D` = c(2.61,2.72,2.46,2.77,2.74,
              1.77,7.23,2.21,1.58,2.75,2.05,0.44,2.42,1.09),
  `E` = c(3.83,5.33,4.44,3.91,4.84,
               5.56,4.14,3.9,2.72,4.5,3.07,2.21,2.91,2.96),
  `F` = c(2.81,4.21,2.81,2.87,3.47,
              3.44,3.92,2.86,2.25,3.06,1.98,1.35,1.87,1.86),
  `G` = c(2.32,3.6,1.99,2.23,2.72,
              2.58,3.12,2.28,1.81,2.28,1.36,0.86,1.67,1.44),
  `H` = c(1.79,3.31,1.71,1.97,2.08,
              2.18,2.89,2.64,1.29,1.85,1,0.72,1.13,0.99),
  `I` = c(1.5,2.07,1.05,1.23,1.91,
              2.01,2.15,1.43,1.43,1.08,0.73,0.34,0.66,0.52),
  `J` = c(1.64,2.02,1.13,1.57,1.6,
              1.51,2.26,2.15,1.23,1.14,0.75,0.58,0.85,0.5),
  `K` = c(2.92,NA,3.2,2.45,3.43,2.24,
              5.59,2.67,1.57,2.39,1.94,1.74,2.76,1.92),
  `L` = c(19.72,16.98,27.77,17.71,
              23.19,28.24,15.43,15.6,16.96,23.1,19.6,15.74,20.23,
              24.62),
  `M` = c(27.51,13.58,13.76,21.61,
              19.51,16.99,NA,11.19,11.39,25.82,9.85,10.83,5.83,
              5.42),
  `N` = c(7.74,4.74,3.71,5.74,6.06,
              4.8,NA,3.84,3.41,6.14,2.56,3.12,1.86,2.06),
  `O` = c(1.63,1.66,1.09,1.49,1.66,
                0.78,3.13,1.76,0.81,1.34,0.89,0.45,0.51,0.5),
  `P` = c(1.56,NA,0.9,1.48,1.6,0.83,
                2.59,1.59,0.88,1.3,0.66,0.41,0.5,0.47),
  Parámetro = c("CO2","CO2","CO2",
                "CO2","CO2","CO2","CO2","CO2",
                "CO2","CO2","CO2","CO2","CO2",
                "CO2")
)

as.data.frame(correlation(a[,1:16],method = "pearson")) %>% select(1,2,3) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = 1,values_from = 3)

cor(a[,1:16],method = "pearson",use = "pairwise.complete.obs")

cor(a[,1:16],method = "pearson",use = "everything")
```

Know how to choose the way missing values are treated with the correlation() function.